# Triggering an email response on newly entered value in a specific column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks a lot like this:

[image]

It's a spreadsheet to help a student with planning for the classwork. I created a column at the end, `Help Needed From`, that is a list of values that are names of their relatives. Let us say that list is `[Alice, Bob, Trent]`. I want to write a spreadsheet function that, upon entering a value in the `Help Needed From` column, an email would be sent out to that specific person with a message like:

`"Eve needs help from you with an assignment from " + row[1] + " class. It is due " + row[5] + " and is a " + row[3] " priority item."`

So `row[1]` would be the `Class`, row[5] the due date, and row[3] the priority. If that wasn't obvious. I have seen scripts only that send emails and stuff, but it seems like its something you have to manually run. *Sure*, I could get the student to do that - but is there a way to automate it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using an installable onEdit trigger.

Comment: @Cooper Speak to me like this is the first time i ever use google spreadsheet's javascript thing because guess what

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
onMyEdit(e) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));//look in executions to see the structure and available values in the event object.  They can save your function a lot of time.
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Your Sheet Name')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==8 && e.range.rowStart>3 && e.value!='') {
    //write you email function here.
    //since sending an email requires permission then this needs to be an installable trigger
    //And keep in mind onedit triggers will time out after 30 seconds.
  }
}
```

[installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[Gmail.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

Comment: Thank you so much, will try soon and get back to you and accept if it works. Appreciate it man